Expression when you call someone just one time and then close the phone to notify him about something
Sometimes you call someone just one time and then close the phone to notify him about something or as a signal to meet somewhere. He and you know that he will not pick up the phone.
What word/expression do you use in german for a call that you make and it rings only one time and then you close the phone. The other one then sees the missed phonecall on his phone and knows (for example) oh i have to go out to open the house door. The call is a used as a signal.

Is there a fixed expression for that in English? Your description reads to me like you also need quite a few words to explain that, without using any fixed expression

@planetmaker - Other than the self-explanatory "let it ring once then hang up", no. Perhaps this post is relevant.

vielleicht "anklingeln"?

Since SMS and messenger applications are now nearly more established  than phone calls, I had assumed that the need for such a word has practically imploded, no?

I know this as "anklingeln". That word was widely used and known in my social circles in Lower Saxony, in the early 200Xs.

I don't understand the downvote, since this word has been in active use in my circles (Berlin) for the last 40 years for exact this purpose.

It's often called anklopfen — to knock (the door).

This is also used when you're in a phone call with someone else and another person rings you. You'll get a sound that someone else is trying to reach you.
